# How to instruct yum to install a specific package (rpm) from a specific repo

Tags: rpm, yum

If the rpm package is available in multiple repos (configured in /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory), yum is scanning all the repo files and installing it from the one which has the latest version of that package.

I want the package to be downloaded from a specific repo, also I don't want to completely disable the other repositories, instead, I want just one package to be fetched from a specific repo, and disable it from getting downloaded from other repo.

I also don't want to use the version as a filter as there could be the same version of the same package present on multiple repos.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you can tell `yum` which repositories he can use:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="<desired-repo-id>" install package-name
```

This does not permanently enable/disable repositories; just for this command execution.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that dependencies have to be installed beforehand if the enabled repo doesn't have them.

Comment: @LucasBustamante which is quite logical... If you have dependencies outside the repositories you use...

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to disable all repos, then only solution here is to use `yum-priorities`. It's a plugin.

```
$ yum install yum-plugin-priorities
```

Then in a yum repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`, you can use,

```
[some_repo]
....
priority=1
```

Note, the lowest numerical value represents the highest priority. If your package is available in multiple repos, installation/update will occur from the highest priority repo.

Read more here: https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities

Comment: This works for `rpm-ostree`.